# Audit log for activating and deactivating features in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have a sharepoint 2010 site. We would like to find who activates and deactives feature in site collection features(site collection level) or Manage site features(subsite level). We are lready having the audit log which does not capture this. Is there any way how to find who is activating and deactivating the feature? Any help is much appreciated.

Sivakumar. P

Comment: are that feature custom?

Comment: No. Its just OOB features. Say for example "Sharepoint server publishing feature".

Comment: can you develop a feature?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think auditing will show you who activates or deactivates features.

But you could set log level to verbose, like this:

```
Set-SPLogLevel -TraceSeverity Verbose -EventSeverity Verbose
```

and then you could look for **____Current User=...***, although I can not guarantee it will work, and setting log level to verbose will of course also have its implications.

Another completely different approach is to do the logging yourself through JavaScript, example with jQuery:

```
$('[value=Activate],[value=Deactivate]').click(function() {
  // Do ajax here
});
```

then you could either use Client Object Model to [get the current user](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4265529) or even just post directly to a WCF Service, which should know what users is calling it, and then log this information in any way you want. For example using [SPLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.upgrade.splog.aspx).